# Importing pipeline with linked services in azure portal

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, azureportal

I have exported my all pipelines (azure data factory) and it is in .zip folder. Now it contains all my pipeline information (json format) with my linked services. When I want to import the zipped folder, I selected **pipeline from template** option, after import I am having all my pipelines but there is no linked services imported, can any one let me know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Linked Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services) are not technically defined as part of the pipeline but rather as part of the Data Factory itself.

Try exporting the Data Factory from either Azure Portal (Export Template button on the data factory) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2linkedservice?view=azps-3.4.0) for the linked services information.

This is common practice with a lot of ETL or ELT like process where the connection string information is defined and shared by the main instance and not defined in the jobs locally.